# The mass-energy equivalence is a principle which can not be derived from anything?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, mass-energy

Not duplication) I couldn't find the answer for the general case, instead of the special case that I already seen in Youtube I hyperlinked.

I will fully satisfy with not only a mathematically rigorous proof, but also just any argument.

For example, I was impressed by the thought experiment(in Youtube : https://youtu.be/hW7DW9NIO9M ) arguing the equivalence principle for the special case that the rest mass of an object actually turned out to be a part of total energy of the object.

Is there any argument like that, but for the general case that the total energy(= rest E's + kinetic E's + potential E) of a system must be the total mass of the system which determines the amount of gravitational attraction and resistance for an acceleration? I think it might require the general relativitistic consideration.

Comment: Hi Sophomore_Jinx. Your question seems an obvious duplicate to me. If you'd like to edit your question to explain what you want to know that isn't covered by the previous question I will withdraw my close vote.

Comment: Several of the answers to the proposed duplicate do exactly what is requested here. I have to agree with John, this is a duplicate.

Comment: But any answer didn't include the potential energy to contribute to the mass of the system. Don't you agree?